# Turning into data.frame into a list based on ids

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a data.frame:

```
DF <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2), event=c("merged", "discussed", "merged", "discussed"))
```

Now I want to turn it into a list, in such a way that the list contains two entries - one for each id (i.e. 1 and 2), and then only the records that correspond to those entries, as such:

```
List of 2:
 [1] name: "1", data.frame
   id     event
 1  1    merged
 2  1 discussed
 [2] name: "2", data.frame
  id      event
 1  2    merged
 2  2 discussed
```

Obviously I am looking for a generalizable solution that will scale up beyond this minimal example.

Comment: You can try `split` i.e. `split(DF, DF$id)` which would be generalizable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with `split`

```
split(DF, DF$id)
```